# Can I add negative margin left and right to an background image?

Tags: css

Can I somehow apply negative margin left and right for 5px on this background css?

```
background: url("/wp-content/themes/custom-1/images/shadows.jpg") repeat-x center bottom;
```

Comment: What do you mean by negative margin to the background? Do you mean negative margin to the containing element?

Comment: You can **offset** the position of a background image but not left and right at the same time. - https://css-tricks.com/positioning-offset-background-images/

Comment: @Paulie_D: Actually it can be (but not by conventional methods). I am not sure what OP is looking for though.

Comment: So still "no" then! :)

Comment: Hahaha, yes @Paulie_D By the way, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q1vqgq7d/) is the method that I was referring to as non conventional.

Comment: If by negative margin you happen to mean *keeping a margin* (which seems to be a more logical request) then something like that can be achieved with padding and background-clip : http://tinyurl.com/pa86cue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make negative margin on the element:

```
.box {
background: url("/wp-content/themes/custom-1/images/shadows.jpg") repeat-x center bottom;
width: 100%;
height:200px;
background-size:cover;
position:relative;
margin: 0 -5px;
}
```

If this doesn't help you please provide us html and css for the element and his parent.